# Send a product name in email when using Chronoform in joomla2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5, chronoforms

I have a contact form which has created using `Chronoforms` component and it is displaying using `Chronoforms` plug-in.

Actually I have different pages in each of which there is a common button name Free Trial.
 Clicking on Free Trial it will open that form in a new pop up window.
In that form there are common fields which I have created by using `Chronoforms` form wizard and so the mail is going with those field values.
But now I want the mail need one more extra value label named as "Product" and it's value will be dynamic regarding which Free Trial button I'm clicking from which page, maybe when I'm clicking the Free Trial from each page it will create a link such as `http://domainname.com/index.php/free-trial/?product=dynamiccontent`.

Any suggestion how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In admin panel of your form (Form Wizard) you can try such way. On tab 'Events' in 'On Submit' area add 'Custom code' `<?php $form->data['product'] = $someProduct; ?>` where $someProduct you can get from $_REQUEST if name of product will be in link. After, you can use {product} in letter ('Custom code' should be before ''Email), for example.